# Responsive Data Tables

Tags: html

I'm trying to make a responsive data grid that can change layouts depending on the width of the screen. I know how to use the media queries but I'm trying to figure out the best way to build the actual data grid. should I use tables, divs or a lists?

The table should render like this if the user in on a desktop:
As you can see I have the header items on the left side and data values to the right.

> Table Header Item 1 | Row 1 Value 1 | Row 1 Value 2 | Row 1 Value 3 |
>
> Table Header Item 2 | Row 2 Value 1 | Row 2 Value 2 | Row 2 Value 3 |

But if the user reduces the size of the screen I want to move the header items on top and the values on the row below

> Table Header Item 1
> Row 1 Value 1 | Row 1 Value 2 |
>
> Table Header Item 2 
> Row 2 Value 1 | Row 2 Value 2 |

I'm thinking using Div's might be my best way to get this result, but does any1 have any other suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: If it's tabular data, using `<table>` is the best way. To make it be "responsive," then all one would need are a few media queries to update the table based on viewport size.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/responsive_design_approach_for_complex_multicolumn_data_tables/) is a fantastic article about hiding elements based on screen width. You use some CSS media queries to turn on and off certain elements with a class of "optional" or "essential." Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

How about this type of thing - set the cells to inline-table:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    #data{width:70%;}
    #data td {display:inline-table;padding:20px;}
    </style>

</head>
<body>

<table id="data">
    <tr><th>Header 1</th>
        <td>row 1 cell 1</td><td>row 1 cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><th>Header 2</th>
        <td>row 2 cell 1</td><td>row 2 cell 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

From my personal experience it is better to go ahead with div than table. On analyzing your requirement div will be the best suited option.